# Replace Upsells with products from a specific product category in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I have the following case - So far I've always set the Upsell products custom, 1 by 1, as choosing a product category in the admin is not possible.

Now after a big cleaning of products that are no longer available, there are many product pages on the site with 1, 2 or 3 instead of the default number of 4 Upsell products, which breaks the design.

Is there a way to replace those upsells with products from a specific product category?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace woocommerce upsells by products from a specific product category use the following code *(where you will define your product category(ies) slug(s))*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_upsell_ids', 'custom_upsell_ids', 20, 2 );
function custom_upsell_ids( $upsell_ids, $product ){
    // HERE define your product categories slugs in the array
    $product_categories = array( 't-shirts' ); // <=====  <=====  <=====  <=====  <=====

    // Return the custom query
    return wc_get_products( array(
        'status'    => 'publish', // published products
        'limit'     => 4, // 4 products
        'category'  => $product_categories, // Product categories
        'orderby'   => 'rand', // Random order
        'exclude'   => array( $product->get_id() ), // Exclude current product
        'return'    => 'ids', // Query returns only IDs
    ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> The query is set to display 4 products from a specific product category in a random order (excluding the current product).

**Official documentation:** [The `wc_get_products()` and `WC_Product_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the support. The thing is - there are hundreds of products and counting. Each of them needs a different source (product category) for Upsell products. I need to be able to set this manually when editing each product separately.

Comment: Hey Loic, unfortunately this code doesn't work after added to functions.php. The urls of the categories are in Cyrillic and so the slugs. After adding them to the code, it breaks the site. I tried with category IDs separated by commas, but no success at all, I'm not getting an option to choose a category when publishing or editing products.

Comment: @StephanG This code perfectly works in Woocommerce 3+ and product categories need to be slugs (and not names) as for sure with  names in Cyrillic it will break the site.

Comment: Urls, respectively slugs itself are in Cyrillic too. Woocommerce is 3.4.6

Comment: @StephanG This is based official woocommerce working code… If the problem comes from Cyrillic characters, you should convert your product categories slugs to non Cyrillic characters to avoid problems. That is all what I can say and sorry, but I am not going to manage foreign characters issues within my code. So you should report this problem to Woocommerce, if it comes from Cyrillic characters in WC_Product_query regarding product categories.

Comment: Hey Loic, I tested your code and it actually does what you mean, but not exactly what I'm asking for :) I need to be able to choose different category with products to show Upsells, for each product separately, from within the admin. There are tens of categories and the products are very different from each other. I hope you understand.

Comment: @StephanG I may have a solution, but I, will do it later on as I have a lot of work now...

Comment: Your support is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no woocommerce_product_get_upsell_ids filter in WooCommerce.

You need to create your own custom woocommerce_upsell_display function and remove the default.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_custom_upsell_display', 15 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_custom_upsell_display' ) ) {
function woocommerce_custom_upsell_display( $limit = '-1', $columns = 4, $orderby = 'rand', $order = 'desc' ) {

// Modified default code
```